# Why does wp add slashes to $_POST?

Tags: escaping

Why does wp add slashes to $_POST values? All my quotes in my $_POST are escaped.. is there a reason for that??

Comment: Are you using [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)?

Comment: found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my

WP escapes all $_POST, etc.. whether you have magic quotes on or off... pfff...